# Create radio Button in PDF using Itextsharp

Tags: pdf, radio-button, itext

I am creating a radio button in PDF by using this code:

```
RadioCheckField checkBox = new RadioCheckField(PDFStamper.Writer, FieldBound, item.Name, item.Value == null ? "On" : item.Value);
PdfFormField field = checkBox.CheckField;
PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(PDFStamper.Writer, true);
radiogroup.FieldName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.GroupName) ? item.Name : item.GroupName);

checkBox.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
checkBox.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(System.Drawing.Color.White);
checkBox.Checked = (item.Value.ToLower() == "true" ? true : false);
//checkBox.FieldName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.GroupName) ? item.Name : item.GroupName);
checkBox.UserName = item.ToolTip;
checkBox.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;
// checkBox.ByDefaultCheck = true;

field = checkBox.RadioField;
radiogroup.AddKid(field);

if (item.ReadOnly)
    checkBox.Options = checkBox.Options | BaseField.READ_ONLY;

if (item.Required)
    checkBox.Options = checkBox.Options | BaseField.REQUIRED;

PDFStamper.AddAnnotation(radiogroup, item.PageNumber);
```

Two radio buttons are created with same group name but when I open the file in PDF only one radio button is shown. What am I missing?

Comment: Only one radio button can be checked at the same time, so you only see the radio button that is checked. If you also want to see the radio button that isn't checked, you need to create a default appearance for the unchecked state.

Comment: Thanks for answering but my finding is i am not able to save the field name each radio button does not contain any name .can u help me how to give field name i have tried alot but nothing happen  field name always remain empty string

Comment: When i add them with different group name its shows both but 1 for each group ??? please help

Comment: Er... different radio buttons that belong to the same group are part of a single field with a single name (the name of the parent). I don't understand why one would give each different possible value of the radio field (that is the group) a different field name. There is only one radio field. That field can have different values. Aren't you confusing the values with the field name?